# OpenGL compressed texture views valid formats

Tags: opengl, textureview

What internal format combinations would work for this following code example, if my intention is to have raw storage allocated as a non compressed texture and the texture view interpreting this as BC5 / RGTC ?

```
GLuint texId;
glGenTextures(1, &texId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, texId);
glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 1, GL_RGBA32UI, 4, 4, 16);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0);

assertNoError();

GLuint viewId;
glGenTextures(1, &viewId);
glTextureView(viewId, GL_TEXTURE_3D, texId, GL_COMPRESSED_RG_RGTC2, 0, 1, 0, 1);
assertNoError();

glDeleteTextures(1, &viewId);
glDeleteTextures(1, &texId);
assertNoError();
```

This example failed with INVALID_OPERATION and the GL debug output message says:

```
Internal formats neither compatible nor identical.
```

To narrow my question by exclusion:

- glCompressed* with pixel unpack buffer is not an option.
- TexStorage cannot have the compressed internal format. This is GL 4.5 and that has been removed.
- OpenGL spec says this following pair is compatible: GL_RGTC2_RG, GL_COMPRESSED_RG_RGTC2. However GL_RGTC2_RG is not a GL define or defined value in any header or the spec.

Comment: "*OpenGL spec says this following pair is compatible*": It says no such thing. Indeed, the letters `RGTC2_RG` appear in exactly one place: as *part* of the define `VIEW_CLASS_RGTC2_RG`.

Comment: [This page](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Storage#Immutable_storage) says that you *can* use compressed internal formats with glTexStorage3D. It is also listed [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glTexStorage3D). I don't see anywhere that it says you can't do it in GL 4.5.

Comment: I would be extremely surprised if you were allowed to create a compressed view of an uncompressed texture. It says that GL_COMPRESSED_RG_RGTC2 and GL_COMPRESSED_SIGNED_RG_RGTC2 are compatible with each other, and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot allocate storage of a non-compressed format and view it with a compressed format. Or vice-versa. You can [*copy* between compressed and uncompressed formats](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Storage#Texture_copy) via `glCopyImageSubData`. But you can't do the kind of "casting" that you're trying to do.

Furthermore:

> TexStorage cannot have the compressed internal format. This is GL 4.5 and that has been removed.

You cannot use *generic* compressed image formats, but specific formats (like `GL_COMPRESSED_RG_RGTC2`) are still available. Just not for 3D textures (BPTC can work with 3D textures, but not RGTC).

---

Vulkan has a mechanism for creating a `VkImage` of a compressed format from which you can then create a `VkImageView` with an appropriate uncompressed format (the reverse isn't allowed, but that doesn't really matter all that much). To do this, the image has to be created with the `VK_IMAGE_CREATE_BLOCK_TEXEL_VIEW_COMPATIBLE_BIT` creation flag, and the view must use a 32-bit unsigned int format, with sufficient components for each pixel of the view to correspond to the block byte size for the format.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where do you take it from that 3D textures don't allow RGTC?

Comment: Copying from the host side (api calls) is not an option for what I need to do. I come from CUDA-land so I assume at least desktop drivers implement image memory and texture views on top in a similar way as here: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__TEXOBJECT.html#group__CUDA__TEXOBJECT_1g1f6dd0f9cbf56db725b1f45aa0a7218a

Comment: I haven't looked into Vulkan deeply yet, but I am assuming Image and ImageView is what makes this happen? Could you point me to a part of the vulkan spec that explicitly disallows this?

Comment: @FHoenig: "*Copying from the host side (api calls) is not an option for what I need to do.*" Then you're out of luck. Maybe there's some NVIDIA extension I don't know about, but as far as standard OpenGL is concerned, you can't do that.

Comment: @FHoenig: "*Could you point me to a part of the vulkan spec that explicitly disallows this?*" Actually, it is possible. Support for it was added in 1.1 (and as KHR_maintenance2 in 1.0), but you have to create the image with a special flag to allow for it.